# Ambiguous column using JDBC but query works fine in database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am connecting to a SQLite database through java using JDBC.

Schema:

```
WorkInfo(id, job, salary)
Person(id, name)
```

This query below runs fine in my database, but when I try it with JDBC:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from Person join workInfo on (Person.id=WorkInfo.id)");
while(rs.next()){ 
    System.out.println("id: " + rs.getInt("Person.id")); //column does not exist
    System.out.println("name: " + rs.getString("name")); //works fine
```

Output:

If using person.id: `no such column: 'person.id'`

Without specifying: `ambiguous column name 'id'`

I've tried using both WorkInfo and Person and using aliases but it keeps throwing the same ambigious column name (if left as id) or column does not exist.

Comment: That is probably because the column name in the result set is not `Person.id` you can try to get the values by index like so: `rs.getInt(1)` or use `rs.getMetaData();` to get the exact column names returned.

Comment: @Titus thanks for sharing `getMetaData()`, I can see this being useful for debugging!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always a good practice to explicitly retrieve the columns you want. I would change the query to be:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select info.id, info.job, info.salary, "
    + "person.id, person.name from Person person join workInfo info "
    + "on person.id=info.id");
while(rs.next()){ 
    System.out.println("id: " + rs.getInt(4));
    System.out.println("name: " + rs.getString(5));
```

In this case, you can use the column index instead of the label.

Or using the `AS` clause:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select info.id, info.job, info.salary, "
    + "person.id as personId, person.name as personName "
    + "from Person person join workInfo info "
    + "on person.id=info.id");
while(rs.next()){ 
    System.out.println("id: " + rs.getInt("personId"));
    System.out.println("name: " + rs.getString("personName"));
```

Comment: I did suspect I probably had to specify column names (I was being lazy)! Thanks for the feedback, your implementation works fine.

Answer (score 1):

After a day of working on this, I achieved it by using resultSet.getMetaData().

```
private int getIndexFromMeta(String column) {
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
        String[] subs = column.split("\\.", -1);
        String tableName = subs[0];
        String columnName = subs[1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            if (meta.getTableName(i).equals(tableName) && meta.getColumnName(i).equals(columnName)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.trace(e);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the ResultSet you're getting back holds the following columns:

- id
- name
- id
- job
- salary

You have two columns named "id" (none named "Person.id"), so when you try to get its' value you either

- Ask for "id" which is ambiguous (which id?)
- Ask for "Person.id" which does not exist

Simply try specifying in your query the columns you want and giving them unique aliases. For example:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select Person.id AS 'personid', name from Person join workInfo on (Person.id=WorkInfo.id)");
while(rs.next()){ 
    System.out.println("id: " + rs.getInt("personid"));
    System.out.println("name: " + rs.getString("name"));
```

Comment: Although it is 'ambiguous', the JDBC specification specifies how this should be resolved (the first occurrence of the column name should be returned), so I don't see why the driver would throw an error here unless it is not adhering to the specification, or it is actually the database that generates the error.